# java set namespace declaration at the beginning

Tags: java, namespaces, jaxb, marshalling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>
> [JAXB: How to avoid repeated namespace definition for xmlns:xsi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2252028/jaxb-how-to-avoid-repeated-namespace-definition-for-xmlnsxsi)

What do I need to set in DocumentBuilderFactory or Document or Marshaller class to move namespace declarations at the beginning of produced XMLdocument? For an example my current code produce next XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<SearchEvents xmlns="http://company/searchevents.xsd">

  <Code return="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>

</SearchEvents>
```

I'm using marshalling class to convert object to document.

I would like to produce the following XML document

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<SearchEvents xmlns="http://company/searchevents.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

  <Code return="true" xsi:nil="true"/>

</SearchEvents>
```

Best regards

Tomaz

Comment: Hi again. I found the answer at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2252028/jaxb-how-to-avoid-repeated-namespace-definition-for-xmlnsxsi