# How can I suppress XSI using JAXB

Tags: xml, jaxb

Default XML output by JAXB2 is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<TEST2 xmlns="http://projects/open/2012/UniformProxySystem">
    <XXX1 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
    <XXX2>17:02:26</XXX2>
    <XXX3 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
</TEST2>
```

but I want it like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<TEST2 xmlns="http://projects/open/2012/UniformProxySystem" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <XXX1 xsi:nil="true"/>
    <XXX2>17:01:08</XXX2>
    <XXX3 xsi:nil="true"/>
</TEST2>
```

Look for someone help, I'm using JDK6 with JAXB 2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this works!

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(
    namespace = "http://projects/open/2012/UniformProxySystem", 
    elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED
    ,
            xmlns={@XmlNs(prefix="xsi",
            namespaceURI="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"),
            @XmlNs(prefix="",
            namespaceURI="http://projects/open/2012/UniformProxySystem")}
)
```

Comment: if I don't add the second XMLNs, there is no default schema, then come a ns2 namespace, so I must set the default schema.

Comment: it seems you should use JAXB2.2+, not native implement in JDK6

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the `@XmlSchema` annotation and do the following:

**package-info.java**

```
@XmlSchema(
    elementFormDefault=XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED,
    namespace="http://projects/open/2012/UniformProxySystem",
    xmlns={@XmlNs(prefix="xsi",
                  namespaceURI="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")}
)
package com.example;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also refer to the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2252028/jaxb-how-to-avoid-repeated-namespace-definition-for-xmlnsxsi) for an alternative solution, especially if you already have a prefix namespace mapper in your program (also useful if you generate your JAXB classes from an XSD).

Comment: XmlSchema annotation really doesn't work, is it the version reason? Is there something different about XmlSchema annotation  between 2.1 and 2.2 ?

Answer (score 0):

I add SCHEMA_LOCATION property to marsheller, that works, but generate  another attr xsi:schemaLocation="...", so I manully delete this attr in generated Docuemnt object.

Answer (score 0):

In java maybe you use

```
        Document document = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().newDocument();
        Marshaller ms = JAXBContext.newInstance(CreateGPSRequest4RAS.class).createMarshaller();

        ms.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
        ms.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, true);
        ms.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_NO_NAMESPACE_SCHEMA_LOCATION, "");
        ms.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING, "UTF-8");

        ms.marshal(gpsRequest, document);
```