# JAXB: How to marshal without repeated namespace

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

My current result of marshalling is this document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<rootElem version="1">
  <list>
    <entry>
      <key xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:string">someValue</key>
      <value xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:string">42</value>
    </entry>
    <entry>
      <key xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:string">otherValue</key>
      <value xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:string">24</value>
    </entry>
  </list>
</rootElem>
```

and I want for marshaller to extract the NS so it doesn't repeat on each element, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<rootElem version="1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <list>
    <entry>
      <key xsi:type="xs:string">someValue</key>
      <value xsi:type="xs:string">42</value>
    </entry>
    <entry>
      <key xsi:type="xs:string">otherValue</key>
      <value xsi:type="xs:string">24</value>
    </entry>
  </list>
</rootElem>
```

How can this be done?

I've found [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2354596/451962) to this problem, but it doesn't solve the problem completely (it just moves the instance to the rootElem).

This is how I marshall it:

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(RootElem.class);
Marshaller m = jc.createMarshaller();
m.setProperty("jaxb.formatted.output", true);
m.marshal(rootElem, file);
```

Comment: Can you show as your marshall method ?

Comment: Appended to the question.

Comment: This one gives you the same output in console: m.marshal(rootElem, System.out); ?

Add this one:
m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

Comment: Of course it does. Why would it give a different output?

Comment: Did you add m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true); ?

Comment: You are aware that: `public static final String JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT = "jaxb.formatted.output";`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103211/discussion-between-saran-and-adam-kortylewicz).